# Graph Theory, complements of isomorphic graphs are isomorphic

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be isomorphic graphs. Prove that the complements of $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic.

Comment: What does "self-complementary both are isomorphism" mean?

Comment: This is rather difficult to understand. Can you restate this more clearly?

Comment: I edited the question to something that almost makes sense, but am not sure if that resembles the askers intention. Whatever self-complementaries are, they are probably trivially isomorphic for isomorphic inputs.

Comment: sorry for bad english.

Comment: "prove that the complements of G and H are isomorphic" is true.

Comment: I vote to NOT close and I ask any one voting to close to cancel my vote.  This is a perfectly acceptable question and it was extremely easy for me to tell what was being asked and the OP has confirmed that what I guessed was correct.

Comment: I repeat, any one who wants to close this question should CANCEL my vote, and NOT actually vote to close, because my vote is AGAINST closing.  This is such a stupid system.  You can't even see my comments.

Comment: @Graphth - is it me or does the question say assume $P$ and prove $P$ ? "Let G and H be isomorphic graphs" but we want to prove "Prove that G and H are isomorphic"

Comment: @Belgi Yes, that was my bad.  Thanks.  In the comments, I asked the OP if he meant that the complements were isomorphic.  OP responded and said yes.  So, I edited the question to add that and somehow I put completely the wrong thing.  Now it's fixed.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to answer the question that I see, which is to "Prove that the complements of $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic."  I can't think of any other possible meaning to the question.

You're telling me $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, so that means there exists a map from the vertices of $G$ to the vertices of $H$ such that $u$ is adjacent to $v$ in $G$ if and only if $f(u)$ is adjacent to $f(v)$ in $H$.

So, now you want to know if the complements of $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic?

**Hint 1:** If $u$ and $v$ are adjacent in $G$, what is true about $u$ and $v$ in the complement of $G$?  Or, if $u$ and $v$ are not adjacent in $G$, what is true about $u$ and $v$ in the complement?  Similarly, with $H$.

**Hint 2:** Use the same $f$ you already know exists since $G$ is isomorphic to $H$.